# Apple Receipt Verification

Tags: ios, google-play, app-store, payment

I am making a mobile app with React Native (it is not submitted yet)

I want to verify apple payment according the this page (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/verifyreceipt)

I'm making test with Postman to post data but getting response "status": 21002.

My request:

```
"receipt-data" : "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",
"password": "702a98fc92d0460bbd6aaf18c9b1ae0d",
"exclude-old-transactions" : false
}
```

And response:

```
"status": 21002
}
```

I tried both https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt and https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt but response didn't change.

I created secret key for app. How can I verify receipt, what is the missing for verification?